# Why does Safari not accept GZIP compression?

Tags: http, safari, gzip

I have a pretty big JavaScript file here which I want to embed into my website. The HTTP server is smart enough to GZIP the file before delivering it to the browser. However, I tested with Google Chrome and Safari. On Chrome, it works very well. 400K go down compressed to around 100k **BUT** on Safari compression doesn't work. The funny thing is that content-encoding is set to "gzip" correctly.

---

**Update:** I already read up on a GZIP-Bug in Safari where files cannot end on ".gz" or Safari won't accept GZIP. Since my file does not end on .gz this problem shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The request headers you got on safari says the content is GZIP'ed, and  its length is 119406 bytes. Are you sure the tool you're using is telling you the truth ?

Comment: @nos It's the same tool. I am just using the web inspector which is built-in to both browsers.

Comment: @nos You were right. Wireshark clearly shows that the file's a lot smaller than the original size. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as "the right answer".

Comment: @Timo Still looking for an answer me too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTTP headers sent to Safari say it's compressed (It has the Content-Encoding: gzip header, and it says the Content-Length is 119406 bytes) - I'd trust those more than the bold number saying **430.61** in Web Inspector. How it determines both those numbers in the top column, , I don't know.

You can get verification on how many bytes is going over the wire if you sniff the HTTP request with wireshark.

Answer (score 10):

I've run into this problem as well, while trying to optimize the load time of a website on iOS7 Safari mobile iPad.

- Encoded = uncompressed filesize, from server
- Decoded = uncompressed filesize, locally
- Transferred = uncompressed file size + headers sent and received
- Content-Length = compressed file sent, from server

Safari chose a really weird way of representing these numbers in their debugger.

Answer (score 2):

This is a while ago but I just came across a very similar issue or maybe the source of this issue. When you compress data with gzip for safari like this:

```
gzip jquery.min.js
```

You will end up with a jquery.min.js.gz which will fail in Safari even when correctly specified as gzip encoded file stream and also when renamed to jquery.jgz as mentioned in a lot of other threads about this issue. This seems to be because the filename is encoded in the gzip file.

If you encode a gzip file like this:

```
cat jquery.min.js | gzip > jquery.jgz
```

Then you will have a file that is a few bytes smaller and does work flawlessly with Safari.