# GZIP compression always 1.00x on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, webserver

I'm looking at the web traffic between iOS 9.2 Safari and our web server and I see that all of our responses are GZIP-ed, but with a factor 1.00x. So we're not saving any bandwidth, which is the whole point.

Does anyone know what could be going on here? Am I overlooking something? Or could something be misconfigured? On any desktop browser the content is perfectly compressed at least with a factor 5.

Thanks!

Pascal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a misinterpretation of Safari Webinspector.
You may find the answer here: http://forums.tumult.com/t/turning-on-compression-enabling-gzip-on-your-server-to-speed-up-loading-times/4762/3

Safari Encoded, Decoded, Transfered, Compression rate is not reliable (or at least, does not have the same meaning as it has in Chrome/Firefox/Edge).

This "Safari feature" has been pinpointed in 2014 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21943693/7173518

Without "content length", Safari get lost in his indicators. And there is no "content length" on Nginx with dynamic gzip activated.

C.

Comment: You dont need or shouldn't  sign, greetings, etc. Answers or questions.

Comment: I dont get your comment, pal. Whatever, the problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In last line, the "C." is useless to your answer and you should remove it. See that [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)