# Safari not passing accept-encoding:gzip, deflate

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, safari, gzip

I am making requests to cloudfront CDN and seeing very frustrating behavior. In chrome and firefox, the request passed the proper `accept-encoding:gzip, deflate` header.

However, safari does not do this and thus gets the uncompressed version of the file. This is a simple script tag in an HTML document. So I can't set the headers.

the same doc produces a request with the following header/browser combos

Safari headers

> -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
>   -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 08 May 2017 18:01:40 GMT' \
>   '

Chrome Headers

> :method:GET
>   :path:/main-b54b8739d65dfbd36152.js
>   :scheme:https
>   accept:*/*
>   accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>   accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   cache-control:no-cache
>   pragma:no-cache

Also, the respective web inspectors provides additional information, in safari,[image: Safari Screen shot]

And in chrome, 
[image]

Additionally, the request takes 3 times longer in safari. 55ms in chrome and 150ms in safari, roughly.

I left out some info to protect my privacy. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suppose that even though Safari does not send this header in the request, most if not all servers will still serve gzip-encoded content nonetheless, because that's standard nowadays. I just verified this, I do get a reply with `content-encoding: gzip` despite the absence of `accept-encoding` header in request. But there are a number of circumstances that can prevent the server from using compression. Also, don't just trust Safari's dev tools to report size that was passed on wire. (As comment because it's just vague indications, not a well-researched answer). Basically: are you sure? :)

Comment: @HuguesMoreau I have added some additional detail and am happy to provide any more information.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the compression. What you should look at is Compressed: Yes. Which means that compression was used in transfer. But compression rate and sizes appear to be broken in Safari. And even request headers seem misreported too. To Apple's defense I had hard time debugging compression some time ago and found all browsers misreporting compression use in one way or another. But that does not help much. If you have control over the server, I'd suggest to log Accept-Encoding header and response size on the server side (access log usually helps with the latter).

Answer (score 5):

Safari uses a different naming convention in their developer tools, which is consistent with your observations. Citing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21943693/4110233),

```
[1] Encoded = uncompressed filesize, from server
[2] Decoded = uncompressed filesize, locally
[3] Transferred = uncompressed file size + headers sent and received
[4] Content-Length = compressed file sent, from server
```

Please check the `content-length` property to see if it's really compressed.